# How come bzr says there is nothing to do on merging branches that differ one from another?

Tags: merge, bazaar

I have a bizarre situation with two bzr branches. The two branches differ one from another as can be seen here:

```
$bzr diff --old=/path/to/another/branch | wc -l
148
```

However,  when I'm trying to merge these two branches, bzr says that there is nothing to do:

```
$bzr merge --preview /path/to/another/branch
Nothing to do
```

I tried to `touch` the files in the another branch in order to modify their modification times, but this didn't help.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it turns out that I had to do `bzr status` in the target branch. Doing this I discovered that

> working tree is out of date, run 'bzr update'

This actually solved the problem. After updating, the both branches became identical, as expected.

Comment: The working tree was out of date, when you do bzr update the working tree is updated from the branch.